# How to find least cost from given product and their properties?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

My melting material should achieve the required property.
There will be 2 sets of material
1) Scrap
2) Ferro Alloys
Objective: To achieve the target value of each element with min cost
For Ex. After 1000 Kg mix, We want to achieve the following property
Carbon - 2.4%
Silicon - 2.1 %
p - 0.015%
S - 0.015%

Now From given sets of material we have defined value that how much we can get
like from CRC ( which is scrap) we can get 1.1% carbon, from carburizer (Ferroalloys) we can get 78% carbon.
That means if we use 100 kg CRC, we can get 1.1 carbon but we use 5 kg carburizer we can get 3.9 carbon.
So we have all the element value for each material.
Also, we have the price of each material. Like CRC is 25 Rs / Kg. and carburizer is 1500 / kg.
so accordingly we need to mix material in such a way that it should achieve target value with min cost like To achieve 2.4% carbon, if we use 100 kg scrap than we can get 1.1% carbon and required 1.4 we can get from  1.8 kg carburizer which cost 2500 + 2700 = 5200 Rs. That can be any number of combination, from which we need to find lowest possible cost solution but the condition is required material should be countable like the answer should be 701.5 than it's fine but it should not be 701.115 as no one is going to measure 115 gram when actually going for a mix.
So we need to find the lowest possible cost and for that how much kg what material should use? this is an example of one element but we should achieve all target element.

Input Data:
Scrap Material and it's element value with it's cost

CRC Scrap        C% - 1.5  Si%- 0.9                          cost: 25 / kg

Pig Iron         C% - 1.9   Si% - 1.1                         Cost:     28 / kg

MS Scrap         C% - 1.4     Si% - 0.9                       Cost:     23.5 / kg

Steel Scrap       c% - 1.8     Si% - 1.5                       Cost:    29 / kg

Ferro Alloys

Carburizer      C% - 80    Si% 0                             Cost:      1000 / kg

Ferro Silicon   C% - 0     Si %- 65         S% 10            Cost:     1200 / kg

Ferro Manganese  c% - 0    S% - 20         P% - 15            Cost:    500 / kg

Copper  cu% - 98                                               Cost:    1500 / kg

Required value is defined above. Now we need to find 1000 kg mix of scrap and for achieving property use of ferroalloys in such a way that cost should be optimum.

Is there any algorithm available for this kind of problem?
Or any method that can help me to find the lease cost?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of this can be stated as a linear program. Once you have this, you can plug it into your favorite solver and get a solution if it is feasible.

The optimization objective you want to minimize is total cost:

```
f = w_CRC * cost_CRC + w_pigIron * cost_pigIron + ...
```

The `w_...` are the weights for each material and represent the optimization variables. The costs are constants.

You then add the following constraints to model your requirements:

```
w_CRC + w_pigIron + w_MS + ... = totalWeight
w_CRC >= 0, w_pigIron >=0, w_MS >= 0 ...
w_CRC * C_CRC + w_pigIron * C_pigIron + ... = desiredCWeight
w_CRC * Si_CRC + w_pigIron * Si_pigIron + ... = desiredSiWeight
```

`C_` and `Si_` are the proportions of the element in the corresponding material and `desiredXWeight = totalWeight * desiredXProportion`.

If you want to make sure that your results are "nice" numbers, you can add integrality constraints and make this an integer linear program. E.g., if you want to allow weights up to the first decimal place, you would replace the weights `w_X` with `0.1 * u_X` and solve for the integer weight factors `u_X`. Then, you get the actual weight with `w_X = 0.1 * u_X`. However, I assume that the original formulation will already give you nice enough numbers, where most weights are probably zero. Additionally, by imposing integrality constraints, you might make the problem infeasible. So, it might be necessary to make these integrality constraints soft. You could do this by changing the optimization objective to

```
f = (... what we had before...) + a * ((w_CRC - 0.1 * u_CRC)^2 + (w_pigIron - 0.1 * u_pigIron)^2 + ...)
```

Here, you would add integer variables `u_X` and make your weights `w_X` close to the represented weight. The constant `a` denotes how badly you want to enforce this constraint.